# How to extract a 0 before '.'

Tags: sql, database

```
select 00.0004 ||' ' || 'USD/MT' from dual
```

this gives the o/p as

```
.0004 USD/MT
```

I also want a 0 before the decimal so that i would get the result as 0.0004 USD/MT

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What DB system are you using? MS SQL? MySQL? Oracle?

Comment: you need to look into formatting your float, rather than manipulation with sql queries.

Comment: Is the query really as simple as that? Then you could use select '0.0004 USD/MT' from dual, but I guess it isn't...

Answer (score 3):

Your `00.0004` variable is being treated as a float (or double) and is being automatically converted into a string using the default conversion format because of the concatenation operator.

If the variable is really a string, enclose it in quotes.

If it's actually a real value being extracted from a database column, use the appropriate function:

```
 TO_CHAR(field, '0.9999')
```

to convert it into an string formatted as required before concatenating it with the other fields.

Answer (score 3):

If it is indeed Oracle - then replace "select 00.0004" with:

select to_char(00.0004,'0.9999')

The to_char function in Oracle as used in this example takes a value as the first parameter, and a format string for the second parameter. The 0 tells the system to preserve this numeric placeholder even when the value is zero.